# instrumental variables

Tags: econometrics, instrumental-variable

I have a question related to IV methods. Suppose I have a regression

$Y = a + b_1 X_1 + b_2 X_2 + \epsilon$,

where $Y$ is a dependent variable and $X_1$ is an endogenous independent variable and $X_2$ is an exogenous one. I have found a variable $Z$ as the instrumental variable for $X$. The question is as follows. Suppose I now set up new variables such that $X_1^l(X_1^h) = 1(0)$ if $X_1 \leq(>) a_1$ and $X_2^l(X_2^h) = 1(0)$ if $X_2 \leq(>) a_2$. The my regression becomes

$Y = a + c_1 X_1^l X_2^l + c_2 X_1^l X_2^h + c_3 X_1^h X_2^l + c_4 X_1^h X_2^h + \epsilon$.

I want to know how to set up IV in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Two ideas: (i) Use $Z_1^j Z_2^k$ as IV's. (ii) Use the control function approach.

Comment: Do you mean $X_1^l Z^l$, $X_1^h Z^l$, $X_1^l Z^h$, $X_1^h Z^h$?

Comment: Oh, $X_1$ is endogenous and $X_2$ is exogenous in your question. Then $Z^j X_2^k$. But I think the control function approach is perhaps better. Please also note that your are in the dummy variable trap. You will need to remove one variable (e.g., $X_1^l X_2^l$).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it.